# Divergence of conservative electric field

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, dirac-delta-distributions, point-particles

I have a little doubt about the following: according Gauss law in the form of Maxwell's equation, we know that:

$$  {\rm div} (D)~=~ \rho(v) $$

This just tells us that the electric field has nonzero divergence if there is some nonzero charge distribution $\rho(v)$.

But, for a point charge $$D=(qk\hat{r}/r^2)$$
 while, in polar coordinates,
$$div(\hat{r}/r^2)=(1/r^2){(d/dr)(r^2/r^2)}= 0  $$ why does this apparent contradiction arise?

Comment: The integral form of Maxwell's equations is better than the differential form in the sense that such singularity won't occur.

Comment: @PuZhang that doesn't make the integral form unconditionally better. In fact one could argue that hiding a singularity is a bad thing, depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

The [electric displacement field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_displacement_field)

$$ \tag{1} \vec{D}(\vec{r})~=~\frac{1}{4\pi} \frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}, \qquad  \vec{r}\neq \vec{0},$$

of a point particle $q$ is *not* a differentiable function $\vec{D}: \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ at the origin $\vec{r}=\vec{0}$.

Nevertheless, it is possible to mathematically interpret Gauss's Law

$$\tag{2} \vec{\nabla}\cdot\vec{D}(\vec{r})~=~q ~\delta^3(\vec{r})~=~\rho(\vec{r})$$

via the theory of [*distributions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29), aka. *generalized functions.* The charge distribution $\rho(\vec{r})$ for a point charge is (proportional to) the 3D [Dirac delta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) $\delta^3(\vec{r})$. One of the characteristic features of the 3D Dirac delta distribution is that it is only [supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29#Support_of_a_distribution) in the origin $\vec{r}=\vec{0}$, as we would expect of a point charge.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Qmechanic answer, you might be interested to look this page too http://physicspages.com/2011/11/14/dirac-delta-function-in-three-dimensions/.